# R - Error in if (order[7] > 1 & sum(order[4:6]) > 0) result <- paste(result, : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, simulation, forecasting, arima, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a bootstrapping process with a Renshaw and Haberman model fit with STMoMo package.
Here is the code :

```
RHboot<- bootstrap(RHfit, nBoot = 2000, type = "semiparametric")
plot(RHboot,nCol = 3,parametricbx=FALSE) 
RHSimPU <- simulate(RHboot, h = forecastTime)
RHSim <- simulate(RHfit, nsim = 2000, h = forecastTime)
print(RHSimPU)
```

After run the the simulation row code I didn't get any error message but after apply "print" function I got the following output:

```
Simulations of Stochastic Mortality Model

Call: simulate.bootStMoMo(object = CBDMaleboot, h = forecastTime)

Simulation based on
Call: bootstrap.fitStMoMo(object = RHfitMale, nBoot = 2000, type = "semiparametric")

kt model: mrwdError in if (order[7] > 1 & sum(order[4:6]) > 0) result <- paste(result,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

which didn't let me then create the confidence intervals. 
The strangest thing is that the same code works perfectly for the model of Lee and Carter. See output attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCArY.jpg)

The code only works with LC model, the only one with one time-varying parameter. It seems to be related to ARIMA order according to the Forecast package code [robjhyndman/forecast](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/newarima2.R)

Could you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved: in RH fitting model code I have changed the weight condition to wxt=1 (default option) instead of wxt =wxt, where:

wxtMale <- genWeightMat(ages = ages.fit  , years = years.fit, clip = 3).

However I continue without noticing why it worked in the LC model since I was using the same condition.
The same message still appears but now I can create the confidence intervals.
Thanks